# Why can't I install tensorflow on windows 10 (python 3.9.0 pip 21.0.1)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10

I tried pip installing it using command prompt, and got this error

```
py -m pip install tensorflow

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: Not available for python3.9 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Tensorflow only supports for python 3.5 - 3.8. As you are on 3.9 it will now work, you need to downgrade your python version for now. When it will support python 3.9 you can upgrade to that version.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is supporting up to Python 3.8 as per [their documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#description).
You have to create new environment with Python 3.8